# Convergence of a sum of expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose the following condition holds :
$$\sum_k \mathbb{E}[\| w_k \|^2 ] < \infty,$$
where $w_k$ is some sequence and $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ is the expectation. I want to show that $\sum_k \|w_k\|^2 < \infty$

Is the following reasoning true :
$$  \sum_k \mathbb{E}[\| w_k \|^2 ] = \mathbb{E}[\sum_k  \| w_k \|^2 ]  $$
by monotone convergence theorem. Since this is finite , we have almost surely $\sum_k \|w_k\|^2 < \infty$.

Comment: Statement is a little vague.  What are $w_k$, sequence of what?  What is $||w_k||^2$?